# Passing parameters using alasql in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, alasql

js in my angular js project to export a grid to excel,
heres my code:

```
 inventaire.exportMyDataVille = function(data) {

        var city='Safi';
        alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("data.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ? WHERE secteur='+city+' GROUP BY secteur,agence,serie', [inventaire.myDataSource]);
    };
```

what im trying to do is to pass a parametre in the alasql but it gives a empty excel file??is there somthing wrong in the request

Comment: alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("data.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ? as dummy WHERE dummy.secteur='+city+' GROUP BY dummy.secteur,agence,serie', [inventaire.myDataSource]);

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap string values in quotes when applying them in SQL clauses.

Based on your previous choice, use double quotes as follows:

`alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("data.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ? WHERE secteur="'+city+'" GROUP BY secteur,agence,serie', [inventaire.myDataSource]);`.

Note the change from `'+city+'` to **`"'+city+'"`**

Comment: That really helped me!!! I was trying to do something like this: (... WHERE name LIKE "%?%"',[name]) and it wasn't working. I did this: (... WHERE name like "%' + $scope.name + '%"')

Comment: This might be vulnerable to SQL-injection attacks. Isn't there a alasql way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the `alasql` function requires the format `( query, [[data], argument, argument, argumentN] )`

So it should be:

```
alasql('... FROM ? WHERE secteur = ? ...', [inventaire.myDataSource, city]);
```

`inventaire.myDataSource` must follow the format `[{secteur:'aaa'}, {secteur:'bbb'}, {secteur:'ccc'}]`